# Force a character (glyph) to be as high as the line-height

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, font-size

I have a font-awesome glyph that has to fit exactly into the surrounding line-height.
As you can see right here, I was not able to do it:
(It's just about the arrow. The text is supposed to not change.)
[image]

```
<table style="width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:30%;">
      {label}
    </td>
    <td>
      <div style="width:100%;border-top:1px solid;border-bottom:1px solid;line-height:{cssValue}">
        <i class="fa fa-arrows-v" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:{cssValue}"></i>abcdefghijkl
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

(The variable {cssValue} contains simple em values between 1.0em and 3.0em.)

Here's my fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/?fiddle=v7#fiddle/1h84

Comment: If you need that much control, consider using an `<img>` element with SVG.

Comment: Hmmm...I'm doubtful this is possible dynamically.

Comment: I can't get it to work. I don't understand how I can make the text inside the svg scale to the line-height of its parent.

Comment: Load the font into a font editor, look at the metrics of the character and do some calculations with the font-size.